# How do I ask about changes over week in percent

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I we need to take one value for day X, take second value for day X - 7, and calculate %. 
The query may look like:

```
select
  edate, count_today, count_lastweek,
  round(
    100.0 * (count_today - count_lastweek) / count_lastweek, 2
  )  as daily_delta
from (
select
   EXTRACT(date FROM ts) as  edate,
    count(1) count_today,
    lag(count(1), 7) over (order by 1) as count_lastweek
  from X
  group by 1
  order by 1 desc
  limit 7) t
```

The results of the last week are not true, trying to understand why
Thanks!

Comment: It's probably the `order by 1` in `lag`, there's no *order by column number* in Windowed Aggregates, thus it's ordering by the *value* `1`. Use `order by EXTRACT(date FROM ts)` instead.

Comment: I got an error "Window ORDER BY expression references column ts which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [10:55]"

Comment: That's strange, `EXTRACT(date FROM ts)` is copied from the Select, I don't k ow about BigQuery, does it allow using the alias? `order by edate`?

Comment: Yes I know this is strange, do you have an idea how it will work?

Comment: First you should check if the `order by 1 ` is actually the problem, simply run the nested Select on it's own and increase the limit to cover multiple weeks (btw, you should add a WHERE to filter unneeded dates before aggregation). Then you can add another Derived Table to calculate LAG ordering by `edate`

Answer (score 1):

There is a bunch I don't understand about this query.  If you are using `lag()`, you are assuming that you have data every day.  Let me make that assumption.

I would expect a query that looks like this:

```
select date(ts) as edate, count(*) as cnt,
       (1 - cnt / lag(count(*), 7) over (order by date(ts))) as one_week_increase
from s
group by date(ts)
order by edate desc
```